# Surface area of a sphere segment proof

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation, area, spheres

I have been searching proof for area of a spherical segment $S = 2\pi Rh$ but ı coulnt find a proper explaining one yet

[image: Spherical Segment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface area of a sphere, or more precisely the zone, is
$$2\pi Rh \\$$
Proof: Let ***R*** denote the radius of the sphere, ***a*** and ***b*** denote the upper and lower radii as shown in your figure, and ***h*** denote the height of the segment.
The surface is a surface of revolution about the z-axis:
$$S(s)=\int{2\pi x \sqrt{1+{x'}^2}dz}$$
Note that we're working in the xz-plane, and the equation of the zone in the xz-plane, is the equation of a circle:
$$x = \sqrt{R^2-z^2} \Rightarrow x'=\frac{-z}{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}} \Rightarrow {x'}^2=\frac{z^2}{R^2-z^2}.$$
Plugging back into our integral,
$$\int_{\sqrt{R^2-a^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-b^2}}{2\pi \sqrt{R^2-z^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{z^2}{R^2-z^2}}dz}$$
$$= \int_{\sqrt{R^2-a^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-b^2}}{2\pi R \space dz}$$
$$= 2 \pi R(\sqrt{R^2-b^2}-\sqrt{R^2-a^2}) \iff \space  2\pi R h \space \space \space \square$$

Answer (score 0):

S(R(h))=2 $\pi$ R(h) ; R is a function of h 
What is 2 $\pi$ R(h) in the first place? 
well its the curved surface area of the spherical zone 
since R changes with the change of h, in the integration world its bounded by [0,h] //it means the area from 0 to h of our main function  
integration = surface =area 
I really don't know how to explain it without using calculus 
You may see this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment

Comment: İ didnt said explain without calculus what i mean is just dont use super complicated theorems when answering